# Explain the output of a c program

Tags: c, for-loop, static

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    static int i=1;
    printf("\nSoftware");                                                                   
    for(;i<5;i++)
        main();
    return 0;
}
```

The output comes out to be an infinite loop. Please explain.

Comment: When you call a function recursively, you have to have some terminating condition, and each call has to make some progress toward that terminating condition, or else you'll just loop forever (or until you run out of stack space and crash). Here the main() call happens before the i++, so there's no progress.

Comment: @AyeshaGupta... Read `for` loop again...This is very simple question...

Comment: classic stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a **main** function from your **main** function. After you call new main function it will print some string and then again it will call **main** function.

Your **i** variable will not be incremented at all, because it is not incremented in the first iteration of for loop. After you call **main**, it will never return to previous main to next iteration of for loop to happen. So the loop will be infinite and **i** will be equal to **1**. Even if you changed the for loop to any other loop, the loop will be still infinite.

I'm including your repaired code, just for the fun of it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int i=0;
    if(i>=5) return 0;
    i++;
    printf("\nSoftware %i", i);
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First to notice that `i` isn't being incremented, so +1. However, it's not an infinite loop. It's an infinite recursion (which will of course crash at some point.) :-)

Comment: But why it will not be incremented?

Comment: @AyeshaGupta Because for it to be incremented, main() must return to the loop. That doesn't happen, so no increment happens either. This is because the for loop executes the `i++` only after the first iteration completes. It never completes in this case.

Comment: Because main will never return to previous main to next iteration of for loop to happen.

Answer (score 1):

When one iteration of Loop finishes then value of **i** is incremented. But in your case before increment it is again calling the **main()** function. Hence your Code is in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an infinite loop.

Your are recursively calling `main` but never give an end to it. This results in a stack overflow.

`i++` is never evaluated, because you never reach the end-of-scope of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't seem to be any difficult or different.In this program for loop do not matter much, so whenever a main() is called inside the same it is definitely a infinite loop.With use of Conditional statements you can restrict the infinite loop. Also that static int do not matter at all.So obviously main get called infinite number of times until time out occurs.
This is infact self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

Calling main function in a loop eats up all your memory and causes stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah definitely the output comes out to be infinite because in `for(;i<5;i++)` the increment of `i` occurs only at the last line of the for loop. So, here the value of `i` never incremented. 
for example:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
int a,b; // just an example
a=10;
b=20;
printf("%d",i);
printf("%d %d",a,b);
// increment of i takes place here at the last line of for loop
}
```

Same as here also:

```
main()
{
    static int i=1;
    printf("\nSoftware");                                                                   
    for(;i<5;i++)
    {    
    main();
    // increment of i takes place here.But compiler never comes at this line .That's why i never incremented .
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code call main function, again and again

```
for(;i<5;i++)
main();
```

Comment: static but for each call it is created again.

Comment: it is not created again for each call, it just is not incremented, see my code example :) there it increments and holds its value.

Answer (score 0):

Its a kind of Recursive Call. Your main function is calling itself resulting into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

i<5 call main()
   i<5 call main()
      i<5 call main()
 
         ...

If u want to call some function 5 times.

## include

```
void myFunc()
{
   printf("\nSoftware"); 
}

main()
{
    static int i=1;                                                                
    for(;i<5;i++)
        myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Im used to c++ so it could be a some small mistake.